# ASP.Net Middleware return 404 instead of processing the request to the correct controller

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

The middleware is being triggered with the correct mapping path but for some reason they all resulting in NotFound (404) status and doesn't proceed to the controller.

If I remove the middleware all request work as intended.

I built a simple middleware "doing nothing for now" in my project here is the middleware class :

```
    public class SessionMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ISessionAPI _sessionAPI;

    public SessionMiddleware(ISessionAPI sessionAPI)
    {
        _sessionAPI = sessionAPI;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
             await next(context);
    }
}
```

Here is all middleware used in my project in the startup config :

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            AllLanguage lg = AllLanguage.fr_CA;
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = context.User;
            lg = cp.GetLanguage(context);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ResourcesAPI.GetLocaleByAllLanguageEnum(lg));
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ResourcesAPI.GetLocaleByAllLanguageEnum(lg));


            await next();
        });

        app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Quotations") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Users") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/ESUsersCompanies") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Fees") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Products") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/UserSettingAdmins") ||
        context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api/Providers"), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>();
        });
```

Here is the service :

```
            services.AddTransient<SessionMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Have you registered `ISessionAPI` in the service collection?

Comment: yes it is and the session api is working fine and not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new appBuilder config does need the default route too, I thought it was implicit.
I added this line:

```
appBuilder.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()
```

below

```
appBuilder.UseMiddleware<SessionMiddleware>();
```